# DBLINK from SQL Server to Postgresql ( Postgis ) avoiding odbc

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, postgis, dblink

I have an issue regarding an dblink that our client ask us to do.

1. Postgres + postgis
2. SQL Server 2008

We will need to have an dblink on (2) that connects to (1) via dblink but the problem is with the odbc that does not support the GIS part.

Is there any other way to make this dblink ?

Thank you all

Comment: I'm quite surprised to hear that the ODBC link fails on the GIS portion...could you describe a bit more on the GIS over ODBC fail?..what are you doing, is there actual error text you could share?  I think you might have to use a function from the PostGIS contribs to convert it into something MS can understand and then read it over ODBC from there.

Comment: Well, meanwhile i've found that possible solution. Hope that it does the job because odbc usually is not very fast and this project works with data that has to be available immediately. Thank you for your suggestion ( now i'm more sure in what to do ). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check dbi-link, it can cannect to everything :)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but your suggestion its to connect from POSTGRESL to another database? That is ok for me because i need it, but imagine that i need to connect from SQL SERVER to Postgresql ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, dbi-link works from Postgres. As for connecting from SQL Server to Postgres, I have no idea.